# Swagger: disabling security on one particular path

Tags: rest, swagger

I have a Swagger file that starts with the following

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "basePath": "/api",
    "schemes": [
        "https"
    ],
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "internalApiKey": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "AAuthorization",
            "in": "header"
        }
    },
    "security" : [
        { "internalApiKey": [ ] }
    ],
```

This prolog applies the security setting to every path that follows in the file.  Eg.

```
"paths": {
    "/foo": {
        "get": {
```

Is there some way I can disable security on just ONE particular Path or Method?

Answer (score 29):

Sure. Simply add the `"security"` property to operation with an empty array `[]` as a value.

So something like

```json
{
  "tags": [
    "pet"
  ],
  "summary": "Updates a pet in the store with form data",
  "description": "",
  "operationId": "updatePetWithForm",
  "consumes": [
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json",
    "application/xml"
  ],
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "petId",
      "in": "path",
      "description": "ID of pet that needs to be updated",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "responses": {
    "200": {
      "description": "Pet updated."
    }
  },
  "security": [

  ]
}
```

would nullify the security for this operation.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work with all systems as its probably not valid schema generally.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
security:
 - NONE: []
```

This worked for me.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59241449/14399624)

Comment: Working doesn't mean it's valid API spec so it may not work with all different systems the implement the schema.