# OpenApi 3.0: override global security

Tags: security, openapi

In OpenAPI 3, is it possible to define a SecurityScheme at global level but then override it at certain endpoints to not use security (for public accessible endpoints)?

For example (taken from https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)

```
openapi: 3.0.0
...
# 1) Define the security scheme type (HTTP bearer)
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:            # arbitrary name for the security scheme
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT    # optional, arbitrary value for documentation purposes
# 2) Apply the security globally to all operations
security:
  - bearerAuth: []         # use the same name as above
```

And then make a given endpoint publicly accessible (unprotected)

```
paths:
  /unprotected/path:
    get:
      security: []
```

Or should this be done in another way?

**Update** this question was marked as duplicate but the other question handles about Swagger 2.x and since syntax is different, I think this question and answers should remain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: disabling security on one particular path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020572/swagger-disabling-security-on-one-particular-path)

Comment: Your example is correct.

Comment: @mvermand consider answering your own question since your example is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed override security on a path bases in OA3 as follows:

```
paths:
  /unprotected/path:
    get:
      security: []
```